# What is the distribution of minimum differences between symmetric bipartitions of a list of i.i.d. random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2N}$ random variables with independent uniform distributions on $[0,1]$.

We look at all possible ways of splitting the $2N$ random variables into two subsets of size $N$, summing them in each subset, computing the absolute difference between the two subset sums, and then finding the minimum such difference found. What is the distribution of this minimum subset-sum-difference? I.e., what is the distribution of
$$
M_N=\min_{\sigma\in S_{2N}}\left|\sum_{i=1}^N x_{\sigma(i)}-\sum_{i=N+1}^{2N} x_{\sigma(i)}\right|
$$
where the $\sigma$ are permutations of $1\ldots2N$?

Is there an analytic expression for this distribution? Or at least an asymptotic expression for large $N$?

#### known results

- The domain of $M_N$ is $[0,1]$ for any $N$.
- For $N=1$ we have
  $$
  M_1=|x_1-x_2|,
  $$
  which is distributed as
  $$
  p_1(M_1)=\begin{cases}
  2(1-M_1) & \text{if $0\le M_1\le 1$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  and has $\mathbb{E}(M_1)=\frac13$.
- For $N=2$ we have
  $$
  M_2=\min\left\{|(x_1+x_2)-(x_3+x_4)|,|(x_1+x_3)-(x_2+x_4)|,|(x_1+x_4)-(x_2+x_3)|\right\},
  $$
  which is distributed as
  $$
  p_2(M_2)=\begin{cases}
  4(1-M_2)^3 & \text{if $0\le M_2\le 1$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  and has $\mathbb{E}(M_2)=\frac15$.
- For $N=3$ numerical evidence suggests
  $$
  p_3(M_3)=
  \sum_{i=1}^3
  \begin{cases}
  c_i(1-i M_3)^5 & \text{if $0\le M_3\le \frac1i$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  with $(c_1,c_2,c_3)=(\frac52,4,\frac92)$, giving $\mathbb{E}(M_3)=\frac{2}{21}$.
- For $N=4$ numerical evidence suggests
  $$
  p_4(M_4)=
  \sum_{i=1}^8
  \begin{cases}
  d_i(1-i M_4)^7 & \text{if $0\le M_4\le \frac1i$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  with $(d_1,\ldots,d_8)=(\frac79,\frac{14}9,4,\frac{56}9,\frac{70}9,6,\frac{49}9,\frac{16}9)$,
  giving $\mathbb{E}(M_4)=\frac{157}{4320}$.
- For $N=5$ numerical evidence suggests
  $$
  p_5(M_5)=
  \sum_{i=1}^?
  \begin{cases}
  e_i(1-i M_5)^9 & \text{if $0\le M_5\le \frac1i$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  with $(e_1,e_2,\ldots)=(\frac{7}{48},\frac{103}{432},\ldots)$.
- For large $N$ numerical evidence (up to $N=9$) suggests an exponential decrease of the expectation value of $M_N$,
  $$
  \mathbb{E}(M_N)=\int_0^1 dM_N p_N(M_N) M_N\approx \exp(1.99 - 1.29 n)
  $$

Comment: I think by CLT, at least that it converges to zero is clear

Comment: You can compute the expected distance fixing a permutation and the minimum would be far asymptotically. See similar ideas in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824238/expected-graph-edit-distance-between-two-random-graphs